# If statement with 2 conditionals not working javascirpt html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement

So I wanted to make a kind of admin login in js so I put two conditionals in the if and else if. I also used arrays to minimize the line of code needed. But it is always running the else block no matter what. I tried putting `===` instead of `==` but still not working.

Here's the Edit EDIT js code:

```js
var avatar = document.getElementById('pfic');
var admin = ['jonh.josh@gmail.com', 'Jonh Josh', '123456'];
var admin2 = ['sam.jackson@gmail.com', 'Sam Jackson', 'abcdefg'];
var access = "no";
var user = document.getElementById('email_input').value;
var code = document.getElementById('password_input').value;
     document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
        if (user == admin[0] && code == admin[2]) {
          avatar.setAttribute('src', 'images/ganiavatar.png');
          access = "yes";
        } else if (user == admin2[0] && code == admin2[2]) {
          avatar.setAttribute('src', 'images/kanatavatar.png');
          access = "yes";
        } else {
          alert("Please make sure you entered the correct creditionals");
          access = "no";
        }
```

And here is the part of html code:

```html
<image scr="images/defult_profile.jpg" alt="defult profile picture" id="pfic">
<input class="input1 input" id="email_input" placeholder="  Phone# / Email"></input>
<input class="input2 input" id="password_input" type="password" placeholder="  Password"></input>
```

Comment: What exactly should `user === user[0]` do? It's the same name here at both sides of `===`, and JS won't be able to magically 'guess' that the first of those actually means the variable set up in the inner function scope because you just thought of it this way. The same issue with `code`.

Comment: As a sidenote, it's even fun to think about all the cases when this statement might evaluate to `true`. :)

Comment: well the ```user``` is and ```input``` and ```user[] ```is the ```array```

Comment: Well, there's no such variable as `user[]`. `[]` is an operator, not a part of identifier. BTW, showing the code creating this `variable' would definitely help here.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Without knowing exactly what data `user`, `code`, `admin` and `admin2` variables contain nobody will be able help you. You said "user is an input" which suggests it's DOM element? And "user[] is an array" - array of what?

Comment: You really need to provide some sample data as per [mcve] and identify what those variables represent

Comment: it is array of strings

Comment: I provided more information about the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the values for `user` and `code` when the page loads, not when the button is clicked. Therefore they'll always be empty strings.

```
var user = document.getElementById('email_input').value;
var code = document.getElementById('password_input').value;
```

To fix the issue, move the above lines inside the button click event handler.

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    var user = document.getElementById('email_input').value;
    var code = document.getElementById('password_input').value;

    if (user == admin[0] && code == admin[2]) {
        avatar.setAttribute('src', 'images/ganiavatar.png');
        access = "yes";
    } else if (user == admin2[0] && code == admin2[2]) {
        avatar.setAttribute('src', 'images/kanatavatar.png');
        access = "yes";
    } else {
        alert("Please make sure you entered the correct creditionals");
        access = "no";
    }
}
```

And if you're not already aware, implementing authentication on the client-side will provide zero protection and is easily bypassed, since the source code is publicly accessible.

Comment: Yeah I am aware this is just sample

Comment: I am going to add an database soon this is just so it can look fancy for now